# cplxblur & qblur setting command

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Hi could anyone help me with the command and the -x264-params of cplxblur 20.0 + qblur 0.5

I have tried

-cplxblur 20.0 and the -x264-params cplxblur=20.0

-qblur 0.5 and the -x264-params qblur=0.5

on the list of settings being used when encoding the cplxblur and qblur settings are not even mentioned.

I have had a look at documentation and websites and I seem to be using the correct commands but as said above they are not in effect / mentioned on FFmpeg or even listed in settings that FFmpeg is using those 2 commands when encoding.

The version of FFmpeg I am using is: ffmpeg version 4.2.2

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The options can be passed only via `-x264-params`, and only in two-pass target bitrate mode when performing the second pass, so use:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -b:v 1M -pass 1 -f null /dev/null
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:v libx264 -x264-params cplxblur=20:qblur=0.5 -b:v 1M -pass 2 output.mp4
```

The options will be (silently) ignored in all other rate-control modes, which means you will not be able to use them in the default CRF encoding.

Comment: Thank you and the 2 pass picks up the cplxblur and qblur but now the problem I have is FFmpeg comes up and says: [libx264 @ 0x7fa57702d600] 2nd pass has more frames than 1st pass (6375).0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
[libx264 @ 0x7fa57702d600] continuing anyway, at constant QP=20
[libx264 @ 0x7fa57702d600] disabling adaptive B-frames. do I put my full settings in the first pass or just the second pass also I am using a Mac so I used /dev/null as when I came across that a few days ago it said only use null /dev/null if using windows. is that correct as I feel I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Add `-vsync cfr` to the 1st pass.

Comment: Thanks Gyan but I did not need that command in the end but thank you for the reply. All sorted now. Thank you ;-)